# Orthant probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, where all variables are i.i.d. For the random vector

$$\mathbf{X} = \left [ X_1, \ \ \ \ X_1 + X_2, \ \ \ \  X_2 + X_3, \ \ \ \  \cdots \ \ \ \   X_{n-2} + X_{n-1}, \ \ \ \ X_{n-1} \right ]^T,$$
how can I find $\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{X} \geq 0)?$ In other words, this is the probability that all components are non-negative.

For small $n$, the probabilities (although tedious) are doable. I was wondering if there is a general form, or bounds, for this probability.

I know that orthant probabilities for $n >5$ do not have a closed form, but in this specific case I believe something can be done, since this is not a classic orthant problem.

The tricky part about this is that the covariance matrix is non-invertible, so I cannot integrate joint densities.

I would appreciate a detailed answer (if one exists). Thanks!

Comment: Do *not* vandalize your question.  I am sorry that you have asked a question which you believe might have been inappropriate for you to ask.  However, once you post a question here, it belongs to the community.  I have previously directed you towards the process of [post dissociation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225986/), if you wish to no longer be associated with this question.

Answer (score 3):

The probability can be analytically calculated by recursion.

Let us decompose the probability to nested functions by using conditional expectations
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{X}\ge0)&= \mathbb{P}(X_1\ge0,X_1+X_2\ge 0,X_2+X_3\ge 0,...,X_{n-1}+X_{n-2}\ge 0,X_{n-1}\ge 0)  \\
&=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{n-1}\ge 0  \}}\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{ X_{n-1}+X_{n-2}\ge 0 \}}  \cdot...\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{X_2+X_3\ge 0  \}} \cdot  \mathbf{1}_{\{X_1+X_2\ge 0  \}}\cdot  \mathbf{1}_{\{X_1\ge 0  \}} \right)\\
&=\underbrace{\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{n-1}\ge 0  \}}\cdot \underbrace{ \mathbb{E}\left(\left.\mathbf{1}_{\{ X_{n-1}+X_{n-2}\ge 0 \}}  \cdot...\cdot \underbrace{ \mathbb{E}\left(\left. \mathbf{1}_{\{X_2+X_3\ge 0  \}}\cdot \underbrace{\mathbb{E}\left(\left.  \mathbf{1}_{\{X_1+X_2\ge 0  \}}\cdot  \mathbf{1}_{\{X_1\ge 0  \}}\right|X_2\right)}_{:=f_2(X_2)} \right|X_3\right)}_{:=f_3(X_3)} ..\right|X_{n-1}\right)}_{:=f_{n-1}(X_{n-1})}\right)}_{:=f_n(\color{red}0)}\\
\end{align}$$

that is
$$\color{red}{\cases{
f_2(X_2)=\mathbb{E}\left(\left.  \mathbf{1}_{\{X_1+X_2\ge 0  \}}\cdot  \mathbf{1}_{\{X_1\ge 0  \}}\right|X_2\right)\\
f_k(X_k)=\mathbb{E}\left(\left.  \mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k-1}+X_{k}\ge 0  \}}\cdot f_{k-1}(X_{k-1})\right|X_k\right) \hspace{1cm} \text{for }k=3,...,n\\
} } \tag{1}$$

---

It's easy to calculate $f_2(X_2)$:
$$\begin{align}
f_2(X_2) &= \mathbb{E}\left(\left.  \mathbf{1}_{\{X_1+X_2\ge 0  \}}\cdot  \mathbf{1}_{\{X_1\ge 0  \}}\right|X_2\right)\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left(\left.    \mathbf{1}_{\{X_1\ge -\min\{0,X_2\}  \}}\right|X_2\right)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(\left.   X_1\le \min\{0,X_2\}\right|X_2\right)\\
&=\Phi(\min\{0,X_2\})\\
&= \mathbf{1}_{\{X_2 \ge 0\}}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}}_{:=P_2(\Phi(X_2))} + \mathbf{1}_{\{X_2 < 0\}}\cdot \underbrace{ \Phi(X_2) }_{:=Q_2(\Phi(X_2))}
\end{align}$$

We observe that $f_2(X_2)$ can be decomposed into the sum of two polynomials of $\Phi(X_2)$ regarding whether $X_2$ is positive or not.
$$\cases{P_2(x) =\frac{1}{2}\\ Q_2(x)= x}$$
By induction, we will prove that
$$\color{red}{f_k(X_k) = \mathbf{1}_{\{X_k \ge 0\}}\cdot P_k(\Phi(X_k)) + \mathbf{1}_{\{X_k < 0\}}\cdot Q_k(\Phi(X_k))\hspace{1cm} \text{for }k=2,...,n }\tag{2}$$

---

Suppose $(1)$ holds true for $k-1$, then:
$$\begin{align}
f_k(X_k)&=\mathbb{E}\left(\left.  \mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k-1}+X_{k}\ge 0  \}}\cdot  f_{k-1}(X_{k-1})\right|X_k\right)\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left(\left.  \mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k-1}\ge -X_{k}  \}}\cdot  \left( 
  \mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k-1} \ge 0\}}\cdot P_{k-1}(\Phi(X_{k-1})) + \mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k-1} < 0\}}\cdot Q_{k-1}(\Phi(X_{k-1}))  \right)\right|X_k\right)\\
&= \color{blue}{\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k}< 0\}}\cdot \mathbb{E}\left(\left. \mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k-1}\ge -X_{k}  \}}\cdot  P_{k-1}(\Phi(X_{k-1}))  \right|X_k\right)}   \tag{3}\\ 
&+\color{purple}{\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k}\ge 0  \}}\cdot \mathbb{E}\left(\left.     \mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k-1} \ge 0\}}\cdot P_{k-1}(\Phi(X_{k-1})) + \mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k-1}\ge -X_{k}  \}}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k-1} < 0\}}\cdot Q_{k-1}(\Phi(X_{k-1}))  \right|X_k\right)}
\end{align}$$

For the blue term, we have:
$$\begin{align}
\color{blue}I &:= \color{blue}{\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k}< 0\}}\cdot \mathbb{E}\left(\left. \mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k-1}\ge -X_{k}  \}}\cdot  P_{k-1}(\Phi(X_{k-1}))  \right|X_k\right)}\\
&=\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k}< 0\}}\cdot \int_{-X_{k}}^{+\infty} P_{k-1}(\Phi(z))\phi(z)dz\\ 
&=\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k}< 0\}}\cdot \int_{-X_{k}}^{+\infty} P_{k-1}(\Phi(z))\Phi'(z)dz \hspace{1cm} \text{change of variable } t =\Phi(z)\\
&= \color{blue}{\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k}< 0\}}\cdot \int_{1-\Phi(X_{k})}^{1} P_{k-1}(t)dt}
\end{align}$$
then we have $Q_{k}(x)$ is a polynomial and is well defined from $ P_{k-1}(x)$:
$$Q_{k}(x) = \int_{1-x}^{1} P_{k-1}(t)dt \tag{4}$$

For the purple term, by the similar technique, it's easy to prove that

$$\begin{align}
\color{purple}J &:= \color{purple}{\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k}\ge 0  \}}\cdot \mathbb{E}\left(\left.     \mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k-1} \ge 0\}}\cdot P_{k-1}(\Phi(X_{k-1})) + \mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k-1}\ge -X_{k}  \}}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k-1} < 0\}}\cdot Q_{k-1}(\Phi(X_{k-1}))  \right|X_k\right)}\\
&= \color{purple}{\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{k}\ge 0  \}}\cdot \left( \int_{1/2}^{1} P_{k-1}(t)dt + \int_{1-\Phi(X_{k})}^{1/2} Q_{k-1}(t)dt \right)}
\end{align}$$
then we have $P_{k}(x)$ is a polynomial and is well defined from $ P_{k-1}(x)$ and $ Q_{k-1}(x)$:
$$P_{k}(x) = \int_{1/2}^{1} P_{k-1}(t)dt +\int_{1-x}^{1/2} Q_{k-1}(t)dt \tag{5}$$

From $(4),(5)$, we deduce that the function $f_k(X_k)$ in $(3)$ can be decomposed into two polynomials and so the formula $(2)$ holds true.

---

Finally, the sequence of polynomials $(P_k(x),Q_k(x))_k$ is calculated as follows
$$\begin{align}
&\color{red}{P_{k}(x) = \cases{1/2& $k = 2$  \\
                  \int_{1/2}^{1} P_{k-1}(t)dt +\int_{1-x}^{1/2} Q_{k-1}(t)dt & $k\ge 3$   }}\\
&\color{red}{Q_{k}(x) = \cases{x& $k = 2$  \\
                  \int_{1-x}^{1} P_{k-1}(t)dt & $k\ge 3$   }}\\
\end{align}$$
and the probability that needs to be calculated is
$$\color{red}{\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{X}\ge0) = f_{n}(0) = P_n \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) } $$

**Remark**: It is possible to determine $f_n(0)$ with a sequence of the polynomial $(P_k(x))_k$ only. From $(5),(6)$ we have:
$$\begin{align}
P_{k}(x) &= \int_{1/2}^{1} P_{k-1}(t)dt +\int_{1-x}^{1/2} Q_{k-1}(t)dt \\
&=\int_{1/2}^{1} P_{k-1}(t)dt +\int_{1-x}^{1/2} \left(\int_{1-t}^{1} P_{k-2}(z)dz \right)dt \hspace{0.5cm} \text{change the order of integration}\\
\color{red}{P_{k}(x)}& \color{red}{=\int_{1/2}^{1} P_{k-1}(t)dt + \int_{x}^{1} \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)P_{k-2}(t)dt+ \int_{1/2}^{x} \left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)P_{k-2}(t)dt} \hspace{0.5cm} k\ge 4
\end{align}$$

---

Let us provide some results. We have:
$$\begin{align}
&P_3(x) = \frac{-4x^2+8x-1}{8} &\implies f_3(0)=\frac{1}{4}\\
&P_4(x) = \frac{-12x^2+24x-1}{48} &\implies f_4(0)=\frac{1}{6}\\
&P_5(x) = \frac{16x^4-64x^3-24x^2+80x+1}{384} &\implies f_5(0)=\frac{5}{48}\\
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
&f_6(0)=\frac{1}{15}\\
&f_7(0)=\frac{61}{1440}\\
&f_8(0)=\frac{17}{630}\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple iterative integral approach to calculate the probability for arbitrarily large $N$, and the Mathematica code is attached at the bottom of this answer. Let me explain how this works. Consider the following density function:
$$ F_N(x) := \Pr(X_{1}\geq0, X_{2}+X_1\geq 0 ,\ldots, X_{N-1}+X_N\geq 0, X_N\in     dx)/dx,$$
and denote $P_N :=\Pr(X_{1}\geq0, X_{2}+X_1\geq 0 ,\ldots, X_{N-1}+X_N\geq 0, X_N\geq 0)$, which is the required probability to be evaluated. As long as we can calculate $F_N(x)$, we immediately have $P_N = \int_0^\infty F_N(x)dx$ by construction. Now notice that we have the following recursive relation between $F_N(x)$ and $F_{N+1}(x)$, which can be easily seen from the  independence between $X_{N}$ and $X_{N+1}$:
$$F_{N+1}(x) =\frac{\Pr(X_{N+1}\in dx)}{dx}\int_{-x}^\infty\Pr(X_{1}\geq0, X_{2}+X_1\geq 0 ,\ldots, X_{N-1}+X_N\geq 0, X_N\in dy)\\ = \phi(x)\int_{-x}^\infty F_N(y)dy,  $$
where $\phi(x) = (2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{-x^2/2}$ is the standard normal density. Therefore, one can evaluate $F_{N+1}(x)= \phi(x)\int_{-x}^\infty F_N(y)dy$ recursively starting from $F_2(x)$, which is simply the following density:
$$F_2(x) := \Pr(X_{1}\geq0, X_{2}+X_1\geq 0, X_2\in dx)/dx\\
= \int_{0\vee -x}^\infty \phi(y)\phi(x)dy=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}\phi(x), \quad x\geq 0\\
\Phi^c(-x)\phi(x), \quad x<0,
\end{cases} $$
where $x\vee y$ returns the larger of $x$ and $y$, $\Phi^c(x):=\int_x^\infty \phi(x)dx$ is the complementary Gaussian CDF function. From here one can easily verify that $P_2 = \int_0^\infty F_2(x)dx = \Phi^c(0)/2 = 1/4$. Now by iteratively evaluating $F_{N+1}(x)= \phi(x)\int_{-x}^\infty F_N(y)dy$, we obtain $P_{N+1}$ as desired. Note that $F_{N+1}(x)$ is in general a polynomial in terms of $\phi(x)$ and $\Phi^c(x)$, but it does not appear easy to write out an explicit formula for an arbitrary $N$. Fortunately, Mathematica can handle such symbolic integration easily, and we get analytical values of $P_N$ for all integer $N\geq 2$. Here is a list of values produced by my Mathematica code:
$$P_2=\frac{1}{4}, P_3=\frac{1}{6}, P_4=\frac{5}{48}, P_5=\frac{1}{15}, P_6=\frac{61}{1440},\\
 P_7=\frac{17}{630}, P_8=\frac{277}{16128}, P_9=\frac{31}{2835}, P_{10}=\frac{50521}{7257600},P_{11}=\frac{691}{155925}.    $$
I'd be surprised if the above sequence can be written as a simple formula of $N$.

---

Here's the Mathematica code to generate the above sequence of $P_N$, and you can alter the choice of K to compute $P_N$ with a larger choice of $N$. You can also check the functional form of $F_N(x)$ from the array PhiAll.

```
K = 10; 
Phi[x_] = 1/Sqrt[2*Pi]/E^(x^2/2); 
Phi1[x2_] = Integrate[Phi[x]*Phi[x2], {x, Max[0, -x2], Infinity}]; 
PhiAll = ConstantArray[0, K]; 
ProbArray = ConstantArray[0, K]; 
PhiAll[[1]] = Phi1[x]; 
ProbArray[[1]] = Integrate[Phi1[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]; 
For[i = 2, i <= K, i++, Phit[x_] = PhiAll[[i - 1]]; 
   PhiC[x_] = Limit[Integrate[Phit[y]*Phi[x], y], y -> Infinity] - 
     Limit[Integrate[Phit[y]*Phi[x], y], y -> -x]; PhiAll[[i]] = PhiC[x]; 
   ProbArray[[i]] = Integrate[PhiC[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]; ]
ProbArray
```